# Hive, join 2 tables by item in array

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I need to left outer join 2 tables by column in an array.

Table one model:

- structure id - string
- ips - an array of strings

Table two model:

- ip - string
- hostname - string

The result I desire is in the format:

id, ip, hostname (if exists)

All IPs from an array in 1st table which have the corresponding ip in the second table need to be matched.

I am unsure how to start, any idea or reference is welcome.

Comment: Models of tables with some example data are needed for people to dive into your question.

Comment: Table one : structure id - string, ips - array of string. Table two : ip - string, hostname - string. The result is : id, ips, hostname (if exists)

Comment: I made some edits to your question.If it's approved I hope it will encourage people to give you an answer since its now more concise and easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the explode option on the second table and then perform the join as below.

Lets say you have a table_1 with array of string names and table 2 is having name

> CREATE TABLE table_1(id string,ips array ); 
>   CREATE TABLE table_2(ip string, hostname int);

Then you can create a lateral view on the table_1 with the explode udf.

> select id, ip from table_1 LATERAL VIEW explode(ips) ep AS ip;

This will explode single row into multiple rows for each value in the array. Please read [Lateral view documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) for more help.

The final join query will be something like this.

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.ip, t2.hostname
FROM 
(select id,ip  from table_1 LATERAL VIEW explode(ips) ep AS ip) AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 
ON (t2.ip=t1.ip);
```